# Can I enable fine-tuned slider controls in Lightroom without holding Shift?

Tags: lightroom

Lightroom allows one to fine-tune the slider controls by holding Shift when moving them. But is it somehow possible to enable the fine-tune controls by default, without having to hold Shift? I find that I usually need fine-tuned adjustments rather than broad strokes, so I always hold the Shift key.

Comment: What happens if you set the *CAPS LOCK* key?

Comment: @MichaelClark nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this seems to be impossible - I've looked through every setting in Lightroom and there doesn't seem to be a feature like this (yet). So I just hold Shift when moving the sliders.